Is Nginx directive "worker_shutdown_timeout" a global directive?
I tried to search in the Nginx documentation, but it does not explicitly mention this nginx config "worker_shutdown_timeout" is a "main"/core directive -- which means when set, it's done globally and it will affect all Nginx services.  Or is this can be an "events" or "http" directive where I can set so it will apply to only certain set of servers?
Tried setting it globally in Nginx, worked.
The downside of this is it applies to all Nginx services and traffic.
Want to confirm if this can be set in more granular way?
